# How do I get the date next week in SQL (Firebird)?

Tags: select, date, firebird

I want to get a date using an SQL statement. For instance, if the date is '2018-08-07' output this should return: '2018-08-14' (one week later). Then I'm going to get the total rows between these dates.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM orders  WHERE dates BETWEEN '2018-08-07'  AND 
DATEADD(day,7,'2018-08-07');
```

However, i get this error because of dateadd() function:

```
SQL Error [335544634] [42000]: Dynamic SQL Error; SQL error code = -104; Token unknown - line 1, column 1; DATEADD [SQLState:42000, ISC error code:335544634]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use  `DATEADD(day,7,date '2018-08-07')` , note the keyword date used.

Consider the following data

```
create table orders(
  dates date
);

INSERT INTO orders (dates)
SELECT  '2018-08-05 ' FROM RDB$DATABASE UNION ALL
SELECT  '2018-08-06' FROM RDB$DATABASE UNION ALL
SELECT  '2018-08-07' FROM RDB$DATABASE UNION ALL
SELECT  '2018-08-08' FROM RDB$DATABASE UNION ALL  
SELECT  '2018-08-09' FROM RDB$DATABASE;

SELECT count(*) 
FROM orders 
WHERE dates BETWEEN '2018-08-07'  AND  DATEADD(day,7,date '2018-08-07');
```

> Result
>
> ```
> COUNT
>   3
> ```

https://dbfiddle.uk/7Vh6wDiw

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked!